# Why when adding a date to an existing array it overwrites previous element in that array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date, datetime

## Problem

At the end of my code, you will notice that the elements being added to the array **datesArr** are somehow being copied to the element in front of it. Also not sure why I'm unable to get the expected output

Example:
**1)** Starting **datesArr = [04/30/2022]**
**2)** Adding date **03/30/2022** to **datesArr[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEHiR.png)** overwrites **datesArr[0]** so then I have an array output that looks like 
**[04/30/2022, 04/30/2022]**

as opposed to 
**[04/30/2022, 03/30/2022]**

See below for console output:
[image]

## Objective

If given a **month-end** in **Date format** and a **frequency**, 
**return an array** which includes the **given month-end** and the **11 preceding month-ends by frequency**.

### Code

```
//Goal: Populate the datesArr with a list of monthend dates for 12 preceding periods(12 elements in array)
/*
Initialize Variables 
datesArray - Holds all dates
initialDate - first month end date that will be placed in the array and every preceding month-end will be calculated based on it
targetDate - Target date is the month end date at the time that will be used to calculate the next preceding month end
frequecy - value that will be used to determine frequency of months (E.g. 1 = 1 month(Monthly), 3 = 3 months(quarterly)). This vaule is used in deltaOfDays function
period - represent the number of month end dates that should be included in the array (E.g. period of 12 is an datesArr of 12 elements)
duration of months - repsents the number of months between month ends(E.g. durationOfMonths = 3 , means quarterly 04/30/2022 to 01/31/2022)
*/

let datesArr = [];
const initialDate = new Date (2022, 03, 30);
let targetDate;
const period = 12;
const durationOfMonths = 1;

//Step1: initialize first element of datesArr with initialDate value and other elements used in for loop

datesArr[0] = initialDate
console.log(datesArr[0])

let numberOfDays; //calculated by deltaOfDays function and represents value of days to be subtracted from targetDate
let newMonthEndDate; // holds the newMonthEndDate value that will be added as the next element in datesArr after being calculated subtracting numberOfDays from targetDate



//Step2: Loop through array period number of times. On each loop identify target element and use it calculate subsequent month end date in the array
for (let i = 0; i < period; i++){
    console.log("Loop iteration #" + i)
    //assign array element to targetDate
    targetDate = datesArr[i];
    console.log("targetDate value is: " + targetDate)

    //calculate the numberOfDays to subtract from the target date such as to arrive at the new monthend date by calling a function deltaOfDays
    numberOfDays = deltaOfDays(targetDate, durationOfMonths)
    console.log("The numberOfDays: " + numberOfDays);

    //subtract the numberOfDays from the targetdate to arrive at newMonthEndDate which is stored as a Date object
    newMonthEndDate = new Date(targetDate.setDate(targetDate.getDate() - numberOfDays));
    console.log("newMonthEnd value: " + newMonthEndDate)
    //assign newMonthEndDate as the next value in the datesArr
    datesArr[i + 1] = newMonthEndDate

    console.log(datesArr)

}


//Function 
function deltaOfDays(targetDate, durationOfMonths){
    //array of number of days per month in reverse (E.g. Jan = daysPerMonth[11])
        const daysPerMonth = [31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 28, 31]
        //set index to begin array based number value of Month ( E.g. Apr = 3 + 1 = 4th  index - 12 )
        //targetDate = strToDateConvert(targetDate)
        
       let  i = Math.abs(targetDate.getMonth() - 12)
       console.log("deltaDays(): i = " + i)
       const j = i
        //Start at initial month and loop through at durationOfMonths - 1 to account for initialization of element[0] already
        for(i; i <= (i + durationOfMonths); i++ ){
            //add days per month to sum
            
            numberOfDays =+ daysPerMonth[j];

            //remove first element of array(DEC) and add to the end 
            temp = daysPerMonth.shift()
            daysPerMonth.push(temp)

            return numberOfDays
        }
    }
```

Comment: what's the point of showing what SHOULD happen three times, but never showing what DOES happen, nor the code you are having an issue with? My guess is, you don't understand that dates are an object - none of that wall of text and expected results has anything to do with the only question you asked *When assigning a Date value to an Array, why does it overwite pervious element in that array?* ... assigning a date value to an array will not do that, unless you assign the same one to every element of an array

Comment: @Psi its not homework. I;m trying to develop something here and stuck. Please see code solution.

Comment: @JaromandaX. Thanks for the feedback. First time posting on stack overflow. I've modified the contents of the post and pasted my code to show what does happen.  I posted that 'wall of text' to see give more context to what I was trying to accomplish just in case someone else could suggest another approach if what I was asking did not ring a bell.

Comment: First issue: `new Date(2022,4,30)` sets the date to 30th May 2022 - is that the issue? [as per documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) the month argument is 0 to 11, not 1 to 12 - fix that, perhaps everything else will work

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX . That was definitely a bug in my code. It does not solve my issue but a step closer. 

I've simplified my post to be more specific to the error I'm getting. Hopefully this helps. 

Much appreciated.

Comment: To be honest, your code is so over complicated for what you want to do! Date's in javascript are more powerful than you think!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: I can't see all the issues in your code, since the code you have is so over complicated for what you want - if you want an answer that uses your code as a starting point, this isn't it :D

This answer takes advantage of the fact that

```
new Date(2022, 4, 0)
```

will result in the LAST day of April 2022 - i.e. since month is 0 based, it's like you're saying "give me the 0th day of May 2022" ... which is the day before the 1st May 2022 ... so, 30 April 2022

Knowing that, and the fact that negative numbers are also allowed in month (in fact in any argument) and the constructor will deal with it for you, the solution is really simple

```
new Date(2022,  4, 0) - April 30 2022
new Date(2022,  3, 0) - March 31 2022
new Date(2022,  2, 0) - February 28 2022
new Date(2022,  1, 0) - January 31 2022
new Date(2022,  0, 0) - December 31 2021
new Date(2022, -1, 0) - November 30 2021
... etc
```

Now - if you want the array to be actual Date objects, then the code is simply

```js
const makeDates = (startYear, startMonth, duration = 1, length = 12) =>
    Array.from({ length }, (_, index) =>
        new Date(startYear, startMonth - index * duration, 0)
    );
    
console.log(makeDates(2022, 4, 1));
console.log(makeDates(2022, 4, 3));
```

before rejecting this snippet, take note that the date is in UTC

If you just want strings as per your expected output:

```js
const makeDates = (startYear, startMonth, duration = 1, length = 12) =>
    Array.from({ length }, (_, index) =>
        new Date(startYear, startMonth - index * duration, 0)
            .toLocaleDateString("en-US")
            .split("/")
            .map((v) => v.padStart(2, 0))
            .join("/")
    );
    
console.log(makeDates(2022, 4, 1));
console.log(makeDates(2022, 4, 3));
```